# I trying to json-server by npm install -g json-server, but everytime I get an error

Tags: node.js, json, npm, node-modules, npm-install

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHLKX.jpg)
This is the error that I am continuously getting after numerous tries. I tried removing node cache, I re-installed node.js but couldn't find success.
However, whenever I am running it with administrator or root, I am able to install it. So why is this happening?

I have provided the screenshot of my error, however, still, I will provide the error in writing.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\json-server
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\json-server'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\json-server'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\json-server'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\7386-85615SG 2913642\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-03T06_29_38_211Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You need to give permissions to your current user or you can install node using your current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command:
`npm config set unsafe-perm=true`

If that doesn't work for you, try changing the folder permissions for your current user for `C:\Program Files\nodejs` with the help of [this](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/)